# rotaion of a falling body in box2D

Tags: box2d

i am try to build a tower brick game
(there are falling shapes from the sky and they should make a tower)
but when i drop the shapes the physics doesnt work and if they on top each other on the corner they do not fall....
how can i fix it?

here is      the shape:

```
var fixDef = new b2FixtureDef;//shape 1
            fixDef.shape = new b2PolygonShape;
            fixDef.density = 0;
            fixDef.friction = 0.5;
            fixDef.restitution = 0.5;


            fixDef.shape.SetAsArray([
                new b2Vec2(-1, 0),
                new b2Vec2(0, -1),
                new b2Vec2(1, 0)],3
            );


            bodyDef.type = b2Body.b2_dynamicBody;    
            bodyDef.position.Set(24.5/30, 60/30);           
            bodyDef.userData = new Traingle();
            addChild(bodyDef.userData);
            world.CreateBody(bodyDef).CreateFixture(fixDef);
```

and here is the world:

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because you've set their density to zero. What impact should a zero-weight body make?

Comment: but if i change the destiny to even 0.1 it rotate when i click on a body
like crazy, and i don't want it to rotate when i hold on a body so much....

Comment: @user2327364: it's another problem, ask another question and explain there what is 'i hold on a body'